# How do you find maximum/minimum values within a JSONField?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

Let's say, I have a JSON field with historical data in the format:

```json
{
    "04-Sep-19": 56456,
    "03-Sep-19": 12551,
    "02-Sep-19": 1616, 
    "01-Sep-19": 0,
    "31-Aug-19": 16161,
}
```

Is there an elegant way to query the database to find the top N maximum/minimum values within this JSONField?

The above example after finding the maximum value:

```json
{
    "04-Sep-19": 56456
}
```

Comment: huh ? i didn't get your question !

Comment: Just create a sorted list, descending and grab first 100 indexes